# Помогите правильно расставить знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите правильно расставить знаки препинания: Мужчина и женщина силой были равны, и, если затевали борьбу, она всегда оканчивалась ничьей.

Answer (score 1):

Мужчина и женщина силой были равны, и если затевали борьбу, она всегда оканчивалась ничьей.

На постановку знаков препинания **влияет местоимение "она"**, из-за чего нельзя переставить придаточное. Соответственно, союз И соединяет первое простое предложение и сложноподчиненное предложение (ставится только одна запятая).

Comment: Разве причина отсутствия запятой после "и" в том, что нельзя переставить придаточное?

Comment: А в чём причина отсутствия запятой? Если у Вас другое мнение, то Вы могли бы дать свой ответ на вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

**Мужчина и женщина силой были равны, и если затевали борьбу, она всегда оканчивалась ничьей.**

Это сложносочиненное предложение, две части которого соединены союзом И, пред которым ставится запятая. Вторая часть представляет собой сложноподчиненное предложение "если затевали борьбу, она всегда оканчивалась ничьей", несколько необычное, потому то придаточное стоит перед главным.

Здесь встречаются два союза И и ЕСЛИ. Ставить ли запятую между ними? Розенталь (§110. Запятая на стыке двух союзов): при встрече сочинительного союза и подчинительного (или союзного слова) запятая между ними ставится, **если изъятие придаточного предложения не требует перестройки главного предложения.**

Пробуем изъять "если затевали борьбу" - предложение теряет смысл. Значит запятая не ставится.

Answer (score -1):

Розенталь:

Надвигалась гроза, и, когда тучи заволокли все небо, стало темно, как в сумерки.

Первое предложение - простое, второе - сложноподчиненное, но запятая после "и" ставится.

Тогда: Мужчина и женщина силой были равны, и, если затевали борьбу, она всегда оканчивалась ничьей.

Comment: Правда, у Розенталя есть и такое: В предложениях типа 

Он давно уже уехал, и где он теперь, я не знаю 

запятая после союза и не ставится.

Comment: Чем этот последний тип отличается отличается от вышеприведенного - непонятно.

Comment: В предложении  "Он давно уже уехал, и где он теперь, я не знаю" первое предложение - простое, второе - сложноподчиненное. Чем же оно отличается от предложения "Надвигалась гроза, и, когда тучи заволокли все небо, стало темно, как в сумерки"?

Comment: Ответ неверный, запятая после "и" не нужна.